# Why can't my OS assign the requested address when using `aiohttp`?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, aiohttp

I'm trying to prove to myself that an asynchronous solution is indeed faster than a synchronous solution.

Both the synchronous solution and the asynchronous solution are requesting data from `baby_api.py`, running on my laptop:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "bing bong we have lift off"}

@app.get("/return_1")
async def return_1():
    return {"value": 1}

@app.get("/return_2")
async def return_2():
    return {"value": 2}

@app.get("/return_3")
async def return_3():
    return {"value": 3}

@app.get("/return_4")
async def return_4():
    return {"value": 4}
```

`async_technology.py` is:

```py
import time
import asyncio
import numpy as np
import aiohttp

async def get_url(endpoint_suffix):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/return_{endpoint_suffix}') as response:
            out = await response.json()
            return out['value']

async def main():
    start = time.process_time_ns()

    task_1 = asyncio.create_task(get_url(1))
    task_2 = asyncio.create_task(get_url(2))
    task_3 = asyncio.create_task(get_url(3))
    task_4 = asyncio.create_task(get_url(4))
    out = await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2, task_3, task_4)
    sum(out)

    stop = time.process_time_ns()
    total_time = stop - start
    return total_time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    times = [asyncio.run(main()) for _ in range(10**6)]
    print(f"Average runtime (nanoseconds): {np.mean(times)}")
    print(f"Runtime deciles (nanoseconds): {np.quantile(times, np.arange(0,1,0.1))}")
```

and `sync_technology.py` is:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import requests

def get_url(endpoint_suffix):
    response = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/return_{endpoint_suffix}')
    out = response.json()
    return out['value']

def main():
    start = time.process_time_ns()

    calc_list = []
    calc_list.append( get_url(1) )
    calc_list.append( get_url(2) )
    calc_list.append( get_url(3) )
    calc_list.append( get_url(4) )
    sum( calc_list )

    stop = time.process_time_ns()
    total_time = stop - start
    return total_time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    times = [main() for _ in range(10**6)]
    print(f"Average runtime (nanoseconds): {np.mean(times)}")
    print(f"Runtime deciles (nanoseconds): {np.quantile(times, np.arange(0,1,0.1))}")
```

`$ python sync_technology.py` works as expected, however when I try `$ python async_technology.py`, following exception(s) are thrown:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1067, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1052, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 963, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/Notes/Technology_Notes/async_technology.py", line 28, in <module>
    times = [asyncio.run(main()) for _ in range(10**4)]
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/Notes/Technology_Notes/async_technology.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    times = [asyncio.run(main()) for _ in range(10**4)]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/Notes/Technology_Notes/async_technology.py", line 19, in main
    out = await asyncio.gather(task_1, task_2, task_3, task_4)
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/Notes/Technology_Notes/async_technology.py", line 8, in get_url
    async with session.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/return_{endpoint_suffix}') as response:
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/marshallmcquillen/python_environments/i3i-3p10-local-dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:8000 ssl:default [Can't assign requested address]
```

Why is this happening? Off the top of my head I wouldn't think I would run out of sockets since I'm only making 4 requests per loop.

Comment: Same here. It has something to do with the certificates apparently but the error message is confusing. However even disabling SSL verification doesn't help. This is a real mystery. I don't expect we will ever find out what is the real issue here.